# Java Variable Substitution

Tags: java, regex, substitution

I am trying to find a way of substituting every `$#` found in a string, where `$` is the literal character `'$'`, and the `#` is a number (with 1 or more digits), and substituting the `$#` with the value of a string in a array at `#` position.

Here are some examples:

1. Input1 (String): `hello $2` Input2 (Array) `dave richard danny` Outcome: `hello richard`
2. Input1 (String): `hi $4` Input2 (Array) `morgan ryan matthew nikoli` Outcome: `hi nikoli`

PS: I just rotated back from C# to Java, so I forgot a lot of things (unless it's the basics like syntax)

The current code:

```
public static String parse(String command, String[] args) {
    String substituted = "";
    substituted = command;

    return substituted;
}
```

I am looking for a function where I can substitute an expression with an String from an Array.

Comment: Please share the code and let us know where you are stuck.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/62576)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I edited

Comment: @KenWhite I edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normally solved with just a `String#replaceAll`, but since you have a custom, dynamic replacement string, you can to use a [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) to efficiently and concisely do the string replacement.

```
public static String parse(String command, String... args) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\d+)").matcher(command);
    while (m.find()) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        m.appendReplacement(sb, args[num - 1]);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/zTw9aO)

Comment: Yep, this works! Thank you! Could you explain to me how it works? I haven't heard of Matcher before....

Comment: The documentation for [`appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) includes another example of how I've used it, and explains what it does.

Comment: Cheers! We need more people like you for noobs like me :(

Comment: Perfect use of `appendReplacement()`. +1. However, although it has nothing to do with regex, I'd also suggest changing `args` parameter to varargs, to make it easier to call with fixed list of values. ;-)

Comment: @Andreas Great idea, kind of like a `printf` style method.

Answer (score 0):

A simple, inefficient solution is to iterate over the replacement array, looking for `#1`, `#2` etc:

```
String[] arr = new String[]{"one","two","three"};
String toReplace = "first $1 second $2 third $3";
for (int i =0; i<arr.length;i++){
    toReplace = toReplace.replaceAll("\\$"+(i+1), arr[i]);
}
System.out.println(toReplace);
```

Output:

```
first one second two third three
```

A more efficient approach would be to iterate once over the input string itself. Here's a quick and dirty version:

```
String[] arr = new String[]{"one","two","three"};
String toReplace = "first $1 second $2 third $3";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0;i<toReplace.length();i++){
    if (toReplace.charAt(i)=='#' && i<toReplace.length()-1){
        int index = Character.digit(toReplace.charAt(i+1),10);
        if (index >0 && index<arr.length){
            sb.append(arr[index]);
            continue;
        }
    }
    sb.append(toReplace.charAt(i));
}
System.out.println(toReplace);
```

Output:

```
first one second two third three
```

Comment: Will it work if the 'variables' would be out of order?

Comment: Could you link me the Ideone? Im on the way to a shop. Sorry!